# responsive design css style for landscape view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I know it sounds a silly question but I've searched through stackoverflow, and most questions discussed about view switching bug when iphone switched from portrait to landscape.

Here is my question.I have designed portrait view for iphone, I manually redefined the width of most divs. The site now works fine in portrait view. Now I am about to develop landscape view, I just want the site be displayed fit into the size of the screen and keep the format as it is displayed in normal browsers. No more design for separate css style sheet for each divs for this view. Just make it be displayed the same format in normal browser but smaller to fit into the size of landscape screen on phones.Is it possible to just set something so that the whole site can be fit into the size?

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:landscape){

        //what can I put here to make the whole site fit into the landscape screen?

}
```

Comment: Have you specified a viewport? This is usually the issue..

Comment: I do have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> defined in header

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood your question, you need a viewport first

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then just set your wrapper's width to 100%, or try a grid system.

Comment: Hi, I have this in my header file: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @Robert I noticed that your media query is wrong, iPhone is 320x480, you set the min-device-width to 481, so it won't be applied.

Comment: try (max-device-width: 480px), and set 100% width to wrapper div

Comment: Hi CodinCat, I've changed according to what you said. When I test it, when phone switch from portrait to landscape, the page is extremely zoomed in and really large. I have to manually zoom out to make it smaller.

Comment: Thank you for this...though it doesn't work for me, but still appreciate your kindly help.